# what is the mechanism for `def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:` in python 3:

Tags: python-3.x, function, arguments

Ｉfound the code as follow in python3:

```
def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    return sum(nums)
```

As I know for python `def`, we only need follow:

```
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
    return sum(nums)
```

what is the `nums: List[int], target: int` and `->List[int]` means? Are those new features of python 3? I never see those.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from typing import List

def twoSum(nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    print(nums, target)
```

Link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Note The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.

Link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting

Comment: after used `from typing import List`, I still encounter the issue for `target: int`: `TypeError: twoSum() missing 1 required positional argument: 'target'`; any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
            for i in range(len(nums)):
                for j in range(i+1,len(nums)):
                    if target == nums[i]+nums[j]:
                        return [i,j]
                    
                    
num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
target = 8

s = Solution()
print(s.twoSum(num,target))
```

#output [0,6]

Answer (score 3):

Python has introduced type hinting, which mean we could hinting the type of variable, this was done by doing variable: type (or parameter: type), so for example target is a parameter, of type integer.

the arrow (->) allows us to type hint the return type, which is a list containing integers.

```
from typing import List
Vector = List[float]

def scale(scalar: float, vector: Vector) -> Vector:
    return [scalar * num for num in vector]

# typechecks; a list of floats qualifies as a Vector.
new_vector = scale(2.0, [1.0, -4.2, 5.4])
```

In the function greeting, the argument name is expected to be of type str and the return type str. Subtypes are accepted as arguments.

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello ' + name
```

Documentation : https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Answer (score 2):

`" nums : List[int] "` states that nums is the name of the list function parameter/variable of type int

`" target: int "` is another function parameter/variable of type int.

`" -> List[int] :"` states that the return type of the function must be a list of integers .

Answer (score 1):

It's a static typing in python for type checking. It allows you to define the type of input parameters and returns so that certain incompatibilities are dealt with beforehand. They are only annotations, not an actual static typing though. Check mypy package for more.

Answer (score 0):

If you've duplicate values in the list, this solution works.

```
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        for j, k in enumerate(nums):
            for x, y in enumerate(nums):
                if j != x and (k + y) == target:
                    return [j, x]
                    break

   nums = [2,7,11,15]
   target = [9]

   print(Solution().twoSum(nums,target))
```